# Get the max value of a column from set of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
Table A:

Id Count
1  4
1  16
1  8
2  10
2  15
3  18
etc

Table B:
1 sample1.file
2 sample2.file
3 sample3.file

TABLE C:
Count fileNumber
16 1234
4 2345
15 3456
18 4567
```

and so on...

What I want is this

```
1 sample1.file 1234
2 sample2.file 3456
3 sample3.file 4567
```

To get the max value from table A I used

```
  Select MAX (Count) from A where Id='1'
```

This works well but my problem is when combining data with another table.

When I join Table B and Table A, I need to get the MAX for all Ids and in my query I dont know what Id is.

This is my query

```
SELECT B.*,C.*
JOIN A on A.Id = B.ID
JOIN C on A.id = B.ID
WHERE (SELECT MAX(COUNT) 
         FROM A 
        WHERE Id = <what goes here????>)
```

To summarise, what I want is Values from Table B, FileNumber from Table c (where the count is Max for ID from table A).

UPDATE: COrrecting table C above. Looks like I need Table A.

Comment: What is id in Table C? What is the difference between count in Table A and Table C?

Comment: From the example data you have above, it doesn't appear that Table A is even needed, since values are duplicated in C.

Comment: @B Seven : Id in Table c same as Id in Table A and Table B.

Comment: @Michael: Values are in Table C, but I wont know whats the max Count number is. Even If I just try with Table B and C, the problem is getting the max value remains. Table C also has multiple counts for a single Id and I need the max value of this set. I can emit table A, but please tell me how to get data from B and C.

Comment: @Ponies: I am using SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: I modified table C. There is no Id in Table C. Sorry I was wrong before. Thats why I need Table A as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: With respect, I disagree with your decision.  There is no such thing as "pure SQL".  ANSI is an attempt to make that happen, but no vendor implements the entire standard.  Knowing the database explains behaviour that can be encountered, as well as alternative syntax, and how to debug/review.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Answers without votes, one of which has a comment about being incomplete.  None are selected answers...  You might think I am wrong, but your justification keeps weakening.  Are you having a bad day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the query you're looking for:

```
select b.*, c.filenumber from b
join (
  select id, max(count) as count from a
  group by id
) as NewA on b.id = NewA.id
join c on NewA.count = c.count
```

However, you should take into account that I don't get why for id=1 in tableA you choose the 16 to match against table C (which is the max) and for id=2 in tableA you choose the 10 to match against table C (which is the min). I assumed you meant the max in both cases.

**Edit:**

I see you've updated tableA data. The query results in this, given the previous data:

```
+----+---------------+------------+
| ID |   FILENAME    | FILENUMBER |
+----+---------------+------------+
|  1 | sample1.file  |       1234 |
|  2 | sample2.file  |       3456 |
|  3 | sample3.file  |       4567 |
+----+---------------+------------+
```

Here is a [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99671/10)

Comment: Thanks very much Mosty. This worked. I am going to try implement the same solution for another problem I was facing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mosty’s working example (renaming the keyword count to cnt for a column name), this is another approach:

```
with abc as (
  select
    a.id,
    a.cnt,
    rank() over (
      partition by a.id
      order by cnt desc
    ) as rk,
    b.filename
  from a join b on a.id = b.id
)
  select
    abc.id, abc.filename, c.filenumber
  from abc join c
  on c.cnt = abc.cnt
  where rk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      PreMax.ID,
      B.FileName,
      C2.FileNumber
   from
      ( select C.id, max( C.count ) maxPerID
           from TableC C
           group by C.ID
           order by C.ID ) PreMax

         JOIN TableC C2
            on PreMax.ID = C2.ID
           AND PreMax.maxPerID = C2.Count

         JOIN TableB B
            on PreMax.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Table C doesnt have Id. I need to get this from Table A. How do I modify?